# openCV method to categorize size of defects

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an image processing problem in which I have 3d images represented by 2d arrays of height data (point cloud).  The application requires the identification of variances in surface height.  The surface that is being scanned is a wood product and thus can have every manner of defect imaginable.  I am utilizing a histogram to threshold the surface and effectively target areas of interest.  Within each area of interest (there can be many on a single image), I need to be able to determine the area and bounding box of the defect.  I could write something to do this, but I am betting OpenCV has a method for this type of problem.  I looked through the OpenCV documentation and nothing stood out to me.

[image]

The images are in a proprietary format, but this is an example.  As you can see from the second from the left, there are two small surface defects.  Thoughts?

Comment: How do you define the defects? an area that as a lot of variation in the height data?

Comment: The surface has a set amount (constant) of "natural variation."  Anything beyond that is considered an anomaly.  Any anomaly that exceeds a certain size (area) is classified as a defect. It all boils down to what is big enough for the human eye to catch at a reasonable distance.

Comment: I don't know if opencv is the solution but you can use a neighborhood operation that will calculate the variance of each area and then threshold this according to a known expected variance. The link is for doing neighborhood operations in matlab https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-sliding-neighborhood-operations.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: provide an example image. there are countless ways of doing things like that. from simple depth statistics to machine learning.

Comment: Adaptive Threshold -> Contour (defects) -> Classify contours (defects) based on area.